# Differences in performance

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Could anybody explain why CODE 1 is better than CODE2 or vice versa:

Some data: computer with **4 cores**, and need to perform **8 independent tasks**, each taks requires a lot of processing, loops, calculations, etc:

**CODE 1: process + thread**

```
results = multiprocessing.Queue()


p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=bigTask1, args=(some_arguments, results))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=bigTask2, args=(some_arguments, results))
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=bigTask3, args=(some_arguments, results))
p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=bigTask4, args=(some_arguments, results))


p5 = threading.Thread(target=bigTask5, args=(some_arguments, results))
p6 = threading.Thread(target=bigTask6, args=(some_arguments, results))
p7 = threading.Thread(target=bigTask7, args=(some_arguments, results))
p8 = threading.Thread(target=bigTask8, args=(some_arguments, results))

p1.daemon = True
p2.daemon = True
p3.daemon = True
p4.daemon = True
p5.daemon = True
p6.daemon = True
p7.daemon = True
p8.daemon = True

p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()
p4.start()
p5.start()
p6.start()
p7.start()
p8.start()


pool_pr += [p1]
pool_pr += [p2]
pool_pr += [p3]
pool_pr += [p4]
pool_pr += [p5]
pool_pr += [p6]
pool_pr += [p7]
pool_pr += [p8]

for p in  pool_pr:
    p.join()
```

**CODE 2: Only process**

```
results = multiprocessing.Queue()


p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=bigTask1, args=(some_arguments, results))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=bigTask2, args=(some_arguments, results))
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=bigTask3, args=(some_arguments, results))
p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=bigTask4, args=(some_arguments, results))


p5 = multiprocessing.Process(target=bigTask5, args=(some_arguments, results))
p6 = multiprocessing.Process(target=bigTask6, args=(some_arguments, results))
p7 = multiprocessing.Process(target=bigTask7, args=(some_arguments, results))
p8 = multiprocessing.Process(target=bigTask8, args=(some_arguments, results))

p1.daemon = True
p2.daemon = True
p3.daemon = True
p4.daemon = True
p5.daemon = True
p6.daemon = True
p7.daemon = True
p8.daemon = True

p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()
p4.start()
p5.start()
p6.start()
p7.start()
p8.start()


pool_pr += [p1]
pool_pr += [p2]
pool_pr += [p3]
pool_pr += [p4]
pool_pr += [p5]
pool_pr += [p6]
pool_pr += [p7]
pool_pr += [p8]

for p in  pool_pr:
    p.join()
```

My main concern is that, if I only have 4 cores available, do I get any benefit using 4 processes + 4 threads?? is it better to force all 4 cores to work (4 processes) + (4 processes) each time??

Comment: Also remember that cPython has the GIL issue, which prevents "real" multithreading. The threaded version will yield an improvement only if the procedure is I/O bound.

Comment: No no, Im just asking for someone with previous experience with multiprocessing/threading, of course no need to profile and nothing like that, I was hoping that, someone very experience could say somethin like "Dont use code 2, its bad, or dont use code1, it is bad practice", etc etc, nothing else

Comment: @Bakuriu: I think you should show more respect to the rest of the comunity, and not just call someone LAZY at the very first comment without even knowing what they are asking. If you are not sure, or if you feel that you dont have enough info, JUST ASK for more, but keep the LAZY and comments like this for other groups, not here.

Comment: @newPyUser You are making a mountain out of a molehill. I do not find the word *lazy* as offensive at all.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Have you seen me calling you ANYTHING but your name??..Take it as an example of use then.

Comment: @newPyUser No thanks, I don't see why I should follow the suggestion of a stranger. And COULD YOU PLEASE STOP SHOUTING AT ME? If you want to highlight something in a comment use the markdown syntax for **bold** (`**bold**`) or *italics*(`*italics*`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"each taks requires a lot of processing, loops, calculations, etc"*

Given this, you shouldn't be using threads at all, because of the GIL. Only one of your threads is ever going to execute at a time, so you won't get any performance benefit. As others have said, threads are only useful if you're primarily doing I/O.

Using `multiprocessing.Process` will allow you to properly scale across all available CPUs, which is what you want. However, it also introduces increased overhead for starting up the processes, and for copying the data you need to send to the workers between the parent and child processes. Depending on how long the work you need to do in each worker takes and how much data needs to be copied, the data copying overhead can sometimes end up being the slowest part of the program, to the point that it makes `multiprocessing` slower than just doing the calculations in a single-threaded/process way.

Also, you may or may not actually see a benefit of using 8 processes over using 4. As others have said, it depends on whether or not you have a hyper-threaded processor. I would recommend using a `multiprocessing.Pool` instead of eight `multiprocessing.Process` objects in this case, so that you can easily switch between 4 and 8 processes, and measure how your program performs with each number:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)  # or 8. Try both.

out_list = []
targets = [bigTask1, bigTask2, bigTask3, bigTask4,
           bigTask5, bigTask6, bigTask6, bigTask8]
for t in targets:
    out_list.append(pool.apply_async(t, args=(some_arguments))   

# You don't need a queue if you're using a pool. Just `return`
# the result from the worker function.
results = [r.get() for r in out_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not memory-bound then I would go with CODE 2. It is simpler and can scale to 8 cores if you get to run it on a different computer.

Comment: Seems like the memory is not a problem in this case, but I have 8 task for 4 cores....that's why the questions about 4proc+4thread

Answer (score 1):

Depends if you have hyperthreading or if you are using the hard disk.

If you have hyperthreading, 8 processes are faster than 4, because you can run them simultaniously. Don't use threads in this case though.

If you use the hard disk or some other slow storage medium, you can use threads and get more throughput because the thread can switch while it is waiting to get the data.

If you have neither, I would shedule workers and let python handle the rest.

Comment: yeah I know that, but remember that I only have 4 cores in the computer, no problem with that?

Comment: _If_ your processor has hyperthreading and 4 cores, you can run 8 processes "simultaneously". It's not as good as 8 cores, but probably still much faster than using only 4 processes.

Answer (score 1):

I feel, you misinterpreted the multiprocessing.Process pattern. It does not mean, that you administer the "bigTask1" to the first Processor and "bigTask2" to second one. It means that python asks the kernel to distribute the workload over the accessible processors instead of adding threads to the heap of the one processor running the GIL. Anyway, distributing over different processors isn't cheap because you need more overhead to sync, reintegrating results ...

Therefore you need to test both approaches to find out, which is faster / less resource hungry. There is a good chance, it'll turn out, multiprocessing.Process is less effective than running all using threads.

Comment: you are right about that, absolutely, I am totally ignorant about it...I think I just know how to make it work, but I dont really know "how it works" or which option is better. Thats why I have to tell THANKS to all of you who spend some time answering.